# Format of the following response?

Tags: java, json, format

I'm using Bing's auto suggest feature to auto suggest me terms given a query. You can find the tool here: http://api.bing.com/osjson.aspx?query=pe as you can see it's returning a strange format that isn't quite JSON. Is this a specific standard different to JSON? I've attempted parsing it as JSON using...

```
        InputStream i = new URL(url).openStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(i, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(readAll(reader));
```

but I get the error `A JSONObject text must begin with '{' found:" at 2 [character 3 line 1]`

readAll =

```
      private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int cp;
        while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
          sb.append((char) cp);
        }
        return sb.toString();
      }
```

Comment: What's the **value** that the `readAll()` function return? Can you post an example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is valid JSON:

```
["pe",["people","people search","petsmart","petco","petfinder","pep boys","people finder","people of walmart"]]
```

It is not object, it is array, which contains string at the first position and another array at the second. So try parse as `JSONArray`, not as `JSONObject`.

Answer (score 0):

A JSON Object starts with a `{` and ends with a `}`, which a `JSONObject` class was designed to parse.
A JSON Array starts with a `[` and ends with a `]`, which a `JSONArray` class was designed to parse.

I hope this helps.